# Draw image in PHP and no image being displayed

Tags: php, image, gd

Folks,I've some 288 points with their X,Y co-ordinates and a value assigned to them. I need to show this figuratively. I tried gd and imagettftext but simple code to draw a blank image isn't working even when I've installed and configured gd.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 300);

// Allocate a color for the polygon
$col_poly = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

// Draw the polygon
imagepolygon($image, array(
        0,   0,
        100, 200,
        300, 200
    ),
    3,
    $col_poly);

// Output the picture to the browser
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

The output in the browser is
[image: no image]

Comment: I tried this code and was hoping to populate the image with text of values.But a simple function isn't working.Might be my GD library isn't configured correctly.

Comment: BTW, why do you set the headers twice, and with different case?

Also make sure you do not have whitespaces in your php file (if you have includes, check those, too).

It's a good idea to fecth the image and view it in a binary editor.

Comment: Thanks,but how do I check whitespaces and view the image in a binary editor

Answer (score 2):

Try to set encoding of php file with your code to **UTF-8 without BOM** (e.g. in Notepad++).

[image]

Comment: You might want to consider explaining how to do this with a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works right and image shows. Most probably your GD library is not working as expected. Try this

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 300) or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
```

Comment: The code is again showing an image logo displayed in the question?? Any idea how to configure GD properly.I have extension=/conf.d/gd.so in php.ini with GD installed already.

Comment: And how are you viewing image? did you try it in an html image tag

Comment: <img src="path-to-your-php-file.php">  sometimes viewing it directly by calling the page doesnt work so try in that img tag on any html page

Comment: Tried it in a different HTML file.Its showing the same image logo.

Comment: I've loosely figured out the problem.If i'm writing the image to a file its getting written properly but the browser is unable to show.

Comment: That sounds like then header is not being properly set. Is there any output being sent before the header call? even a blank space or a new line will break the header call